# Are enemies aware of Hunter's Quarry, Bravo prey, etc?

Tags: dnd-4e

If a ranger is hidden and quarries an enemy, is the enemy aware of it? Is the ranger's position revealed?

Are the rules the same for a [Bravo's prey](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1280)?  I'm sure there are other effects out there too, but these are the two my party has to deal with.

The debate arises from the wording of the player's handbook and that of Hunter's Quarry

> Whenever you affect a creature with a
> power, that creature knows exactly
> what you've done to it and what
> conditions you've imposed. For
> example, when a paladin uses divine
> challenge against an enemy, the enemy
> knows that it has been marked and that
> it will therefore take a penalty to
> attack rolls and some damage if it
> attacks anyone aside from the paladin.

> **Hunter's Quarry**
> Effect: You can designate the nearest enemy to you that you can see as your quarry.

**Is designating a creature as your target considered affecting a creature with a power?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Player's Handbook, pages 57-58*
>
> Whenever you affect a creature with a power, that creature knows exactly what you've done to it and what conditions you've imposed. For example, when a paladin uses *divine challenge* against an enemy, the enemy knows that it has been marked and that it will therefore take a penalty to attack rolls and some damage if it attacks anyone aside from the paladin.

Citation shamelessly copied from @okeefe's answer; any errors in it are his ;-)

Additionally, to clear up any and all confusion on whether or not Hunter's Quarry is subject to this rule (i.e. is it a "power" or not?), consider that the citation specifically singles out the Paladin's Divine Challenge as an example of a *power* that is subject to this rule.

But Divine Challenge, which is directly cited as an example of when and how this rule is applied, is a Paladin class feature. From the [Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=4):

> **Class features**: Channel Divinity, Divine Challenge, Lay on Hands.
>
> ...
>
> **DIVINE CHALLENGE**
> The challenge of a paladin is filled with divine menace. You can use the divine challenge *power* [emphasis mine] to mark an enemy of your choice.

And take a look at the Ranger's entry in the [Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=5):

> **Class features**: Fighting Style, Hunter's Quarry, Prime Shot, Running Attack.
>
> ...
>
> **HUNTER'S QUARRY**
> Once per turn, you can use your Hunter's Quarry *power* [emphasis mine].

I think this all makes it quite clear that yes, any NPC would immediately know it was the target of a Hunter's Quarry, however nothing in here gives any suggestion that the Ranger's hidden position would be compromised -- the Ranger is still hidden, but the NPCs could now be more on alert that *someone* is around. Additionally, depending on flavor text, a GM might rule that certain powers like this might be too flashy to do while remaining hidden, or might give a penalty to the character's Stealth check.

Comment: Citation please? I'd gladly give an upvote for the citation.

Comment: This definitely clears up that Hunter's Quarry is a power.  But I'm not convinced that Hunter's Quarry falls under the "what you've done to it and what conditions you've imposed" category. Divine Challenge, sure, because the creature will have a penalty if he doesn't attack the paladin.  But with quarry there are no effects or conditions.  The ranger just hits harder.

Comment: Not that everything in D&D has to make sense (wee I'm running faster diagonally!), but here's an example of why I'm not convinced: Randy the Ranger sneaks within bow range of Krusty the Kobold.  Randy thinks to himself, "I'm gonna kill that Krusty guy good." Why would Krusty be aware of this?

Comment: @dpatchery Because Randy isn't simply hitting harder (that would be a critical hit and/or a called shot), he's invoking the powerful primal energies against Krusty. While you're right that Hunter's Quarry doesn't invoke any penalties on the target, it nonetheless *does* put an effect on the target, namely allowing the Ranger to dish out more damage. Extra damage most certainly does affect a creature, regardless of what the fluff says about the method of such.

Comment: @dpatchery Characters don't run faster diagonally since horizontal distance equal diagonal distance ^_^ But I caught the sense of your comment.

Comment: @Kromey: What's this about primal energies? Rangers that have the *Hunter's Quarry* class feature have only martial as a power source, not martial and primal like the hunter and scout rangers.

Comment: @admjford Ah, my mistake, I was going off of pure memory with the Ranger's power source. Regardless, I stand by my assertion that Hunter's Quarry is a power that affects a creature, and thus said creature would know it is the target of said power, regardless of the power's source. I don't see it as any different really than marking or Divinely Challenging a target (in fluff terms, a "marked" target is really nothing more than the target of a greater level of concentration and focus, same as the target of Hunter's Quarry).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the enemy is aware of the Hunter's Quarry.  No, the location of creature that caused the effect is not revealed.

> *Player's Handbook, pages 57-58*
>
> Whenever you affect a creature with a power, that creature knows exactly what you've done to it and what conditions you've imposed. For example, when a paladin uses *divine challenge* against an enemy, the enemy knows that it has been marked and that it will therefore take a penalty to attack rolls and some damage if it attacks anyone aside from the paladin.

Comment: I agree with you, even if _technically_ Hunter's Quarry is not a power (even if it could be easily designed so).

Comment: I was aware of this rule. But, as Erik said, Hunter's Quarry is not *necessarily* a power that affects the creature.  The ranger is simply designating that enemy as the quarry. Edited the question to bring up this debate.

Comment: It's only an at-will, minor action, ranged, class feature that the character builder creates a power card for.

Comment: _Combat challenge_ is a Fighter class feature that marks targets. I would hope that it falls under the same ruling, namely, that the creature knows that it is marked.

Comment: @Erik and @dpatchery, there is no question that Hunter's Quarry is a power. See my updated answer for citations that directly address this.

Comment: I stumbled upon the Compendium update just now. ^_^ Now _Hunter's Quarry_ has been promoted to a whole power.

Answer (score 1):

> Player's Handbook, pages 57-58
>
> Whenever you affect a creature with a power, that creature knows exactly what you've done to it and what conditions you've imposed. For example, when a paladin uses divine challenge against an enemy, the enemy knows that it has been marked and that it will therefore take a penalty to attack rolls and some damage if it attacks anyone aside from the paladin.

The Hunter's quarry is ONLY a designation and has no effect all by itself.  In that respect it is more like the Rogue's Sneak Attack than the Paladin's Divine Challenge or the fighter's Combat Challenge.  With the Paladin's and Fighter's marks the creature affected can avoid or lessen the effects of the power by behaving in a certain way.  That is not so with either the Rogue's Sneak Attack or the Ranger's Hunter's Quarry abilities.

Similar to the Rogue's Sneak Attack, there is no actual effect until a successful attack is made, at which point the creature knows exactly what you've done to it in either case, in accordance with the rules in question.  Until that point you have done nothing to it and have imposed no conditions, so there is nothing for the creature to be aware of.

From the role-playing point of view the Hunter's Quarry ability is simply the fact that the ranger is concentrating and paying attention to a single enemy. There is no magic involved and no communication between the ranger and his quarry. There is nothing at all to alert the creature that the Ranger is concentrating on them any more than there is an indication that a concealed Rogue is considering dealing some Sneak Attack damage on a future attack.

For these reasons I feel that not only would the Ranger's position not be revealed but also that the Ranger's existence would not be revealed to the creature for which the designation was made.

Comment: This answer definitely seems right to me; +1.